# Corona SDK game scenes

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk, scene

I looked in many other questions and tutorials, but sadly, without result.
I am trying to go from scene1 to scene2 with event listener and I am copying the code which was given in the project. The only difference between my button and the working one is that I declare mine in the lua file and it does not exist in the scene1.ccscene
Do I have to put an image as an object in scene1.csscene in order to use it as a button?

the code I try:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here
local start_button = display.newImage("START.png")    --start button

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
    start_button.x=200
    start_button.y=150
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
        function nextScene:touch ( event )
                local phase = event.phase
                if "ended" == phase then
                    composer.gotoScene( "scene2", { effect = "fade", time = 300 } )
                end
            end
        start_button:addEventListener( "touch", nextScene )
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
        if nextSceneButton then
            start_button:removeEventListener( "touch", nextScene )
        end
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension of the scene files needs to be "`.lua`" in Corona. I think "`csscene`" has something to do with Cocoa.

The code below will work.

Notes:

- Make sure that the files ends with .lua (`main.lua`, `scene1.lua`, `scene2.lua`).
- `start_button` is now a rectangle but you can easy change it to an image.
- `start_button` is added into sceneGroup. This is the group that the scene will use i.e. when you change the scene all objects in the sceneGroup will be handled properly.
- I add the `eventListener` in a different way, please read the documentation for more information: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html

main.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
composer.gotoScene("scene1")
```

scene1.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- VARIABLES
local start_button

-- EVENTS
local function onTouchStartButton( event )
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        composer.gotoScene( "scene2" )
    end
end

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Create the start_button
    start_button = display.newRect( 100, 100, 100, 100 )

    -- Make sure you insert the button into the sceneGroup
    sceneGroup:insert( start_button )

    -- Set position of start_button
    start_button.x=200
    start_button.y=150

    -- Add the event listener in the "create" stage instead of the show state
    -- Now the start_button is in the scene_group so there is no need to remove
    -- the touch listener under the "destroy" stag
    start_button:addEventListener( "touch", onTouchStartButton )
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

scene2.lua:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- local forward references should go here

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Initialize the scene here.
    -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
end


-- "scene:show()"
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
        print("Now we are in scene2.lua!")
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
        -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
        -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end
end


-- "scene:hide()"
function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
    end
end


-- "scene:destroy()"
function scene:destroy( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
    -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
    -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
end


-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```